# How to solve these 3 equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

**We're told that $3x = 2y$.
We also know: $x + (2 + t)y = 60$.
$ty$ must $= 20$.
Find the values for $x$, $y$ and $t$.**

The answer is: $x = 10$, $y = 15$ and $t = \frac{4}{3}$. But I have no idea how to get these values. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $ty = 20$, you have two equations

$$ 3x -2y = 0, \\
x + 2y = 40. $$

If you multiply the second by equation by $3$ and subtract from it the first equation, you get

$$ 8y = 120 \implies y = 15 $$

and then $x = 40 - 2y = 10$ and finally $t = \frac{20}{y} = \frac{20}{15} = \frac{4}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

We know: $x + (2 + t)y = 60 \implies x +2y + (ty) = 60 $

$\text{because } ty=20 \implies x+2y+20=60$

Combined with the first equation you obtain:

$$3x=2y$$
$$x+2y=40.$$

Solving from here should be manageable.